# Detecting editor exit events in Sublime

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

Is there a way to detect editor exit event in Sublime 2?

It is not listed in the [API reference](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html#sublime_plugin.EventListener) and I've tried using `EventListener.on_close`, but that works only for detecting view closing, which is not what I need.

I just want to execute something before the editor exits, is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this in ST2. In ST3, you could try to capture the `exit` command by using [`sublime_plugin.EventListener.on_window_command()`](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime_plugin.EventListener), or possibly `on_text_command()` (not sure what kind of command `exit` is, probably do both for safety), but I've never tried it myself.