# sublimetext3 event for program exit

Tags: python, plugins, sublimetext3

Is there a possibility to capture an exit or quit in ST3? 
I saw this older question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27150846/detecting-editor-exit-events-in-sublime) and I tried both the `on_windows_command` and the `on_text_command` but neither seems to trigger the quit/exit!?

It there's none, it would also be fine if I could handle it on a restart of sublime, but the `on_load` doesn't seem to be called again on remembered views!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no way to tell when ST exits: https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/10

The reason why `on_load` isn't called for remembered tabs when ST loads is because your plugin hasn't loaded yet. You can use the [`plugin_loaded` method](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#plugin_lifecycle) to tell when your plugin has loaded and then manually cycle through all windows and all views, but this will also be executed when your plugin is updated, so you may want to think about how best to work around that.

Comment: How would you access the views from the `plugin_loaded`?

Comment: `[window.views() for window in sublime.windows()]`